# Setting an instance to null or create a new instance with new

Tags: java

Does this:

```
// Class 'Refresh' inherits class 'Thread'
Thread refresh = new Refresh(paramOne);
...
refresh = null;
refresh = new Refresh(paramTwo);
```

And this:

```
// Class 'Refresh' inherits class 'Thread'
Thread refresh = new Refresh(paramOne);
...
refresh = new Refresh(paramTwo);
```

Have the same result?

Does assigning a new class instance on an existing object null out the first class instance?

Comment: Why do you think this would not be the case?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I don't know, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: What lead you to believe that there would be a difference? Did you preform any experiments in code that would cause you to believe this? Did you read something that would lead you to this conclusion?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Well I did find out now that there **is** a difference so my question was not that bad.

Comment: Those are side effects from poorly written that you selected as the answer, which theoretical and aren't really practical in nature, as it you would not encounter them in correctly written code. They don't change that fact that assigning things to `null` is redundant and pretty much a `NOOP` in correctly written code.

Comment: I wanted to know those side effects so my answer is now definitely answered. And define correctly written code; what is not correct in my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually they don't quite have the same result.

In the first case if an exception is thrown while constructing `new Refresh()` then `refresh` will still be `null`. In the second case `refresh` will still be the first object constructed.

Assuming `new Refresh(paramTwo)` does not ever throw an exception or the refresh variable is not visible outside the current context then the two are equivalent.

```
public class Main{

  static class Boom {
    Boom(boolean noBoom) {
    }
    Boom() {
       throw new RuntimeException();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
   Boom boom1 = new Boom(true);
   try {
     boom1=null;
     boom1=new Boom();
   } catch (Exception ex) {};
   System.out.println(boom1);

   Boom boom2 = new Boom(true);
   try {
     boom2=new Boom();
   } catch (Exception ex) {};
   System.out.println(boom2);

 }
}
```

Try it:
http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/52cd952fe4b00bdc99e8ab38

Result:

```
null 
Main$Boom@d35755c
```

Comment: Oh I wasn't worried, I hit the rep cap most days anyway - was just curious if I had missed anything but since the -1 has gone I guess not :)

Comment: I think the other answers (including mine) weren't thinking about cases like this. The two can also potentially have different results in a multithreaded environment. In any case, +1.

Comment: Interesting answer, I was thinking about something like this, that the old reference would still exist. Thank you for confirming and explaining it :). The example is just perfect!

Comment: Yes, multithreading is the other case but in that case you would expect a synchronized block. I've added a working test for the exception case now anyway to demonstrate the effect :)

Comment: I **am** using multithreading (note the comment in my question: class `Refresh` is an inherited class of `Thread`). What's the case now?

Comment: Basically if two threads are accessing the variable at the same time then in the first case one MAY if it hits at exactly the right/wrong time briefly see it as null, in the second case it won't. But since refresh isn't volatile you should only be doing that inside a synchronized block in any case so it won't actually effect you.

Comment: @TimB I totally get it now :) What I basically want to do is completely end that thread and null it out and create a new object and start that thread.

Comment: Yep, either is fine for that. You should look at `ExecutorService` (its in the core Java libraries) though as you probably don't need threads at all in this case - let the `ExecutorService` handle all that for you.

Comment: @TimB I will do some research right away, thanks for all the provided information!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. Assuming no other references to the original value remain, that value is eligible for garbage collection either way.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference.

```
refresh = null;
```

Is redundant here. It wont make any difference.

When you write

```
refresh = new Refresh(paramTwo);
```

Existing reference is overriding anyway. So no matter what it is previously.Weather it is null or still holding some instance won't matters.

Comment: Actually in this case it was me. :( I only down-voted it to reverse the previous up-vote and the reason for that is simply because the answer is slightly inaccurate as it does make a difference in some situations. "Existing reference is overriding anyway" is the line that is incorrect as it is only over-ridden if the construction of the new Refresh() succeeds.

Comment: Thanks Tim for commenting :) Haven't got that thought even and went for a coffee ;)